# Aws::S3::Errors::InvalidAccessKeyId (The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-ruby

On a Rails 6 app I use aws-sdk-s3 with ActiveStorage and I want to upload images.

Steps:

- I created a IAM User on AWS with S3FullAccess
- I configured storage.yml (see below)
- I created an config/aws.rb file with the following

Here is my configuration

```
# Gemfile
gem 'aws-sdk-s3', '~> 1', require: false

# storage.yml
amazon:
  service: S3
  access_key_id: ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID']
  secret_access_key: ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
  region: eu-west-1
  bucket: mybucketname

# config/aws.rb
require 'aws-sdk-core'

Aws.config.update(
  region:      'eu-west-1',
  credentials: Aws::Credentials.new(ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'], ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'])
)
```

I have a simple model with:

```
has_one_attached :picture, dependent: :destroy
```

On development everything works fine, but not on production.

For eg..

```
> model_object.picture.attach(io: File.open(Rails.root.join('testfile.png')), filename: 'testfile.png')
> Aws::S3::Errors::InvalidAccessKeyId (The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.)
```

Environment variables are correctly visible from console, so I don't think it's a configuration issue...

```
ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID']
ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
```

What could I do?

---

To make sure I had the correct AWS access policies I uploaded an image using APIs directly from console like this:

```
require 'aws-sdk-core'

Aws.config.update(
  region: 'eu-west-1',
  credentials: Aws::Credentials.new(myakid, mysecret_key)
)

s3 = Aws::S3::Client.new
resp = s3.list_buckets
resp.buckets.map(&:name) # He gave me the list of my buckets

resp = s3.list_objects(bucket: 'MYBUCKET', max_keys: 2)
resp.contents.each do |object|
  puts "#{object.key} => #{object.etag}"
end

# upload
resource = Aws::S3::Resource.new
object = resource.bucket(MYBUCKET).object("completed.png")
object.upload_file(Rails.root.join('app/assets/images/completed.png'))
```

And the file was correctly uploaded.

So, I cannot understand why ActiveStorage doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that, somehow, Aws.config returned an empty object.
I had to restart the server and now..

```
Aws.config
=> {:region=>"eu-west-1", :credentials=>#<Aws::Credentials access_key_id="XYZ">}
```

Images are now uploading!